# Distributed uncompression of a file archive

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, distributed, tar

A bash scripting question. Suppose we have a calling host H and a remote server S. Is it possible (using a ssh remote invocation of tar from H to S) uncompress a file archive residing on S (and thus using computing resources of S) such that the files and directories of an archive are created only on H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tarball is gzipped, you can remotely gunzip it and locally untar it with

```
ssh S gzip -dc < archive.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

For this to actually be fast you need a very fast network and a very slow workstation.

You can't untar the archive remotely unless you have a shared filesystem (NFS, CIFS, ...).

Comment: that's useless as the overhead introduced by SSH encryption will be at least similar to that of decompressing the file locally... and that leaving along that you are requesting `ssh` to use compression!!!